# How to access data only once ALL of it is ready

Tags: node.js, stream

I have seen some code such as this:

```
  .on('error', console.error)
  .on('data', function (data) {})
  .on('info', function(info) {})
  .on('end', function() {
    // All data retrieved.
  });
```

I have read some docs about streams, but am having trouble understanding them. Say I only want to do the operations once all the data is received (not partial). How can I do this? I would think I would have to read the data object inside of the 'end' function, but the data object is not accessible from there.

From my understanding if I put some logic inside of the 'data' function I could be operating on incomplete data? Is this true? Say data is a list of friends (some lists have 1 friend some can have 10,000 so the size of the data returned back will be different). How can I only do operation once ALL the friends are returned no matter the size of the data coming back?

Answer (score 1):

The `data` handler will usually be called multiple times, each time with a fraction of the complete data.

If you want to perform an action *once* with *all* data, the usual way is as follows:

Buffer all the items received in the `data` handler in some variable (e.g. add to an array) and perform your final action in the `end` handler. (although the idea of a stream naturally is, to "act" right away).

```
var allData = [];
stream
.on('error', console.error)
.on('data', function (data) {
    allData.push(data);
 })
.on('info', function(info) {})
.on('end', function() {
    // TODO do something more intelligent,
    // where buffering in memory makes sense
    console.log(allData.join());
});
```